# How do I insert new project and update old project in an array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to insert a new project and update the old projects in an array.

Here's what I want to do in pseudo-json.

How to update project A in MongoDB?

```
{
  _id : ...,
  userName: milad ,
  projets : [
    { .. projectId, pName, location .... A },
    { .. projectId, pName, location .... B },
    { .. projectId, pName, location .... C },
  ]
}
```

How to insert Project D in MongoDB?

```
 {
      _id : ...,
      userName: milad ,
      projets : [
        { .. projectId, pName, location .... A },
        { .. projectId, pName, location .... B },
        { .. projectId, pName, location .... C },
        { .. projectId, pName, location .... D },
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `$push` operation while using `findOneAndUpdate()` for inserting new document

```
  db1.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: 1 }, { $push: { projets: {name:"bbbbb" }} });
```

For updating a single array element use the following

```
   db1.findOneAndUpdate({ id: 1, "projets.projectid": 2 }, { $set: { "projets.$.name": "cccc" } });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   const insertProjec= async (newProject, _id)   { 

  let projectObj = await Project.findOne({_id})

  let updatedProjectArray = [...projectObj.projects, newProject]

  let updatedProject = await Project.findOneAndUpdate({_id,{projects:updatedProjectArray})
   }
```